# Reload only after Post request has been done

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$('.active-per').click(function () {
    var text = $(this).data('value');
    $('.active-per').removeClass('active');

    if (text == "t") {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $.post("percentage.php", {
            'text': text
        }, function (data) {});
    } 
    else if (text == "n") {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $.post("percentage.php", {
            'text': text
        }, function (data) {});
    } 
    else if (text == "c") {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $.post("percentage.php", {
            'text': text
        }, function (data) {});
    } 
    else if (text == "r") {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $.post("percentage.php", {
            'text': text
        }, function (data) {});
    }

    window.location.reload();
});
```

I need to refresh my page only after post request has been done.But if i do like this its not happening.I can t get the post variable i have sent after refresh.How to reload only after the post data sent.

Answer (score 0):

All the `$.post` methods inside `IF` - `ELSE` condition so `1` request will be post at a time, so you can assign `post` function states in variable and check at the end of code.
try this way

```
$('.active-per').click(function () {
    var text = $(this).data('value');
    $('.active-per').removeClass('active');

    var ajax = null;

    if (text == "t") {
        $(this).addClass("active");
       ajax = $.post("percentage.php", {
            'text': text
        }, function (data) {});
    } 
    .
    .
    .
    else if (text == "r") {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        ajax = $.post("percentage.php", {
            'text': text
        }, function (data) {});
    }

    ajax.done(function(){
     window.location.reload();
    });
});
```